# Another way of saying 'Physically, mentally, psychologically, spiritually(maybe?)'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

Is there Another way of saying 'Physically, mentally, psychologically, spiritually(maybe?)'

So instead of saying

> Drugs are bad 'Physically, mentally, psychologically...

is there a nice phrase or a word to convey this meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word [Systemically](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/systemically?s=t) would cover the entire body and its subsystems.  In your example, you could say, "Drugs are systemically bad," or "Drugs are a systemic problem."

Comment: Great word :-)! In a technical context it can be paired with adverse/side effects: *drugs have/cause systemic side effects* or *systemic adverse effects*